# Vnc using Ubuntu 17.10 with Wayland

Tags: ssh, 17.10, vnc, wayland

I was wondering if anyone could give an update on the state of `vnc` in Ubuntu 17.10 with Wayland, and if it is possible, some instructions on how to set it up. The `vnc` documentation on the Ubuntu community wiki is relevant for an x11 server, but not Wayland.

As background to my question, I used to regularly use `x11vnc` to remotely set up `vnc` over ssh, but go figure, no `x11` means `x11vnc` no worky. Now, my office desktop is running Wayland and I can't figure out how to get GUI access while I am traveling. One of the reasons I want the GUI is that the computer appears to be set to automatically suspend after a certain time and I haven't been able to figure out how to turn that off from the command line (I have been sending people in to my office to hit the power button every so often). I tried using `tightvnc` to create a x11 virtual desktop, which it appears to have done, but when I connect with `vnc` I just get a blank gray screen with an X for the mouse, presumably because all the gnome bits are off in Wayland space...

Comment: Related: https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/wayland-gnome-remote-desktop Probably not working yet…

Comment: you can start gnome using X

Comment: I know that I can choose a xorg session on login, but I don't see how to do that at a distance with a Wayland session already running...

Comment: As I remember, vnc simplicity was one of the original arguments for Wayland, so it is kind of shocking this doesn't work yet...